# naive dd-wrt user - limiting pings to my home network - are subnets useful?

Tags: networking, dd-wrt

I am trying to set up connectivity for a guest Ubuntu VM run on a Windows 8 host laptop.  I want to be able to connect to it from other machines on my home network.

That's not working, but I can connect to the services within the guest and from its host.

Now, looking at DD-WRT Status/LAN page, I can see the IP assigned to that guest - 192.168.1.102

When I try to ping, I don't get any reply, but I also see that it's my ISP that is replying that it can't find it.

```
 user@explore$ ping 192.1.168.102
```

output (isp info changed):

```
PING 192.1.168.102 (192.1.168.102): 56 data bytes
76 bytes from 261-19-191-1.myisp.net (261-19-191-1): Destination Net Unreachable
Vr HL TOS  Len   ID Flg  off TTL Pro  cks      Src      Dst
 4  5  00 5400 d8bf   0 0000  3f  01 784f 192.168.1.138  192.1.168.102
```

Isn't 192.1.168.xxx supposed to be in my "local network area"?  Isn't that what subnets are for? And how can I refrain from pinging out to my ISP when I am only looking for this machine internally?

Does DDWRT's Setup/Advanced Routing tab have something to offer here?  It's empty for me right now.

No big deal, just a bit of curiosity about my pings leaking out.

Comment: There’s a (pretty obvious) typo in your `ping` call. That’s why the traffic is leaving your own network.

Comment: `ping 192.1.168.102` itself?  I edited the surrounding info a bit for privacy (bash prompt and the output), so there may typos there.  can you elaborate or at least point me in the right direction?  Sorry, managing networks is not my strongest point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably intend to ping 192.168.1.102 and not 192.1.168.102. 
To highlight the differences:

```
192.168.1.102 
192.1.168.102
```

192.168.x.x is standard for local networks and I can see your source address is in the 192.168.x.x range whereas the destination address is not.

Comment: err... I feel **dumb**.  I am a bit dyslexic with numbers, and I probably was re-running it from bash history all the while without ever rechecking it.  Good catch.